# Understanding the result of applying a linear transformation to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

There are two related concepts I do not grasp.

- A linear transformation is determined by its action on a basis.
- The action on a basis can be arbitrary.

Can someone give insight into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an example.

The standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is $(1,0), (0,1)$. We first **arbitrarily** pick an image for $(1,0)$. We have to make two choices: the $x-$coordinate of its image, and the $y-$coordinate of its image:

$$L (1,0) = (x_1, y_1).$$

Next we **arbitrarily** (this does not depend on or is in any way restricted by our previous choices!) pick an image for $(0,1)$. Again we make two choices.

$$L (1,0) = (x_2, y_2).$$

We have now made four choices which will completely determine our linear transformation. This is *exactly* the number of elements in your matrix, and this is not coincidental. We can now calculate the image of an arbitrary vector. Why? Let $(a,b)$ be an arbitrary vector. By linearity:

$$L(a,b) = a \cdot L(1,0) + b \cdot L(0,1) = a \cdot (x_1, y_1) + b \cdot (x_2,y_2).$$

Comment: Seems very valuable what you shared. Two related questions, if I may ask. Don't you need a formula to computer the image? Aren't both images related; how can I choose in an independent way images for both of the basis vectors?

Comment: The last equation in my answer is the formula you need to compute the image. The images are not related; I'm afraid that's just something you have to know. The image of $(1,0)$ has no effect on what the image of $(0,1)$ can be.

Comment: Thank you. This “rule of correspondence” can be anything I want? I learn that a function maps every element of the domain to one element of the codomain. Can you explain what is the relationship with what you just told me?

Comment: Linearity is quite a strong condition and fixes all images once you have chosen the images of a base set. The size of the base set depends on your dimension of the domain.

Answer (score 1):

If you know $$T(b_1), T(b_2),...,T(b_n)$$

where $$\{b_1, b_2,...,b_n\}$$ is a basis for the vector space then you know $T(v)$ for every $v$ in your vector space because $$T(v)= T(\alpha_1b_1+\alpha_2b_2+...+\alpha_nb_n )= \alpha_1T(b_1)+\alpha_2T(b_2)+...+\alpha_nT(b_n)$$